# How do I implement a generic class with a generic type parameter without specifying the value for the type

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

Let's say I have

```java
public abstract class GenericClass<T> {
  abstract T getValue(T value);
}
```

I want to sub-class this with a class that works for any `List<U>`. Is it possible to implement this without having to do `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` and `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`? For example, this works:

```java
public class ListClass extends GenericClass<List> {
  @Override
  List getValue(List value) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

but I have to use `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` to get ride of the compiler warnings. I want to avoid doing `ListClass<U> extends GenericClass<List<U>>` because my `ListClass` doesn't actually care what `U` is so client's shouldn't have to have separate instances for `ListClass<Double>` and `ListClass<Integer>` (for example).

Note: my real code uses `CompletableFuture` and is obviously more complicated and I end up having to add ugly casts and `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` when I try to use the extension methods off of `CompletableFuture` such as `future.exceptionallyAsync((e) -> handleException((Throwable) e))`.

Ideally I would want something like this to work (but it doesn't recognize the method as a valid override):

```java
public class ListClass extends GenericClass<List> {
  @Override
  <U> List<U> getValue(List<U> value) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, those "clients" that you are talking about are using this through `ListClass`, and not through the interface of `GenericClass`, right? Because the clients cannot get different types of lists just from the signature `T getValue(T value);` with just one instance of `GenericClass`.

Comment: You probably just cannot do this.  Sorry.

Comment: You could use `List<?>`, but that would limit the usefulness.